# Chatter:FeedWithFollowers width Problem

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

im using chatter:feedwithfollowers to integrate chatter into our ordering system however when ive inserted this within a pageblocksection its become skewed and certain sections are overlapping each other ive tried the pageblocksection columns="1" technique but that doesnt seem to affect it, ive read somewhere max width is 420px but surely that wouldnt cause overlapping?[image]

Further to this Question is it possible to have the chatter feed only show items specific to the custom object/ visualforce its on??

currently using this:

```
            <chatter:feedwithfollowers entityid="{!$User.Id}" ></chatter:feedwithfollowers>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it happen across multiple browsers? Can you share your VisualForce code?

Comment: Hi, im using chrome but its also the same in IE, i fixed it in the end using jquery to alter the salesforce css code

Comment: Glad you were able to work around it. If you can provide a simple repro to the original problem, I can try to get it fixed. I tried to put a <chatter:feedWithFollowers> inside an <apex:pageblockSection> and couldn't repro the problem.

Comment: `<apex:outputPanel >
<apex:pageBlock >
<div id="chattertest" style="display:inline;">
<chatter:feedwithfollowers entityid="{!$User.Id}" ></chatter:feedwithfollowers>
                            </div>
                        </apex:pageBlock>
                    </apex:outputPanel>`

Comment: for some reason not allowing me to format into code

Comment: Thanks, but it's strange... after pasting in your code, I'm not able to repro the problem in Chrome.

Comment: for some reason when i first go into the page the problem constantly appears however when i refresh the page it disappears and listens to the jquery i installed

Comment: @ClevelandDan - was the '<chatter:feedwithfollowers>' inside an apex:form on your page? I'm facing similar issue, but your solution to use 'display:inline;' does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

this is how to fix this error.

```
<apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <div id="chattertest" style="display:inline;">
            <chatter:feedwithfollowers entityid="{!$User.Id}">
            </chatter:feedwithfollowers>
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```